# Where do I find a live CD with octave?

Tags: linux, livecd, octave

I'm working on a project involving octave. It's difficult to tie up my work computer with running the calculations so I thought to do it on an old laptop. That computer doesn't have an OS currently so I figured I'd run a Linux live CD.

Is there a live CD out there with the latest version of octave?

Also, if I run a regular 64 bit live CD then intend to connect to the internet and install octave, is that possible? If it is, which distribution would be best suited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ubuntu. I have tested on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. It ships with Octave 3.8, but there is a PPA for 4.0. I don't know of any distro that ships with the latest version of octave.

After you have booted into the live CD, start Ubuntu Software Center. Navigate to Edit->Software Sources. There, enable "Community-maintained free and open source software (universe)".

Next, open a terminal an execute the following:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave
```

The first command will install this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/ubuntu/stable.
The next command will update the package cache and the last will install octave 4.0.
The last command will also pull down a large number of dependencies.

After that, you can start octave.